# skimage imread from temporary file

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to `skimage.io.imread()` an image (say a tiff file, for concreteness) that was previously written to a `tempfile.TemporaryFile()`. However, `skimage` complains by saying

```
   ValueError: Cannot determine type of file b'<_io.BufferedRandom name=6>'
```

I am doing this because another program writes the image to standard output.
I collect it with `subprocess.check_output` and write it to the temporary file, thus avoiding saving the image to disk.

Does anyone know how to achieve this, or has got a better idea on how to pipe an image from stdout into a python image, ultimately to be treated as a `numpy.ndarray`?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is the following

```
with NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    skimage.io.imread(f.name, plugin="tifffile")
```

Alternatively, one can replace `freeimage` with `tifffile`.
Earlier I was passing the file object, but `imread` actually wants a filename.